# Galaxy Nexus: Sensor Sampling Rate becomes faster when sampling more Sensors

Tags: android, performance, android-sensors

I'm trying to read out sensor values as fast as possible from a Samsung Galaxy Nexus (with Android 4.0). For this I did a few experiments using different sensors and sampling rates and figured out a very weird behaviour. When I use only the Acc-Sensor the sampling-rate is about 50Hz. But when I also use the Gyro-Sensor (or magnetic-field-sensor) the sample-rate of the Acc-Sensor increases and both have a sample-rate of between 90 and 100 Hz. A change of the sensor-delay (e.g. from SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST to SENSOR_DELAY_UI) has no effect on the sampling rate and when I add also the magnetic-field-sensor all three sensors have a high sampling-rate (90-100Hz).
Another strange thing is that the values from the three sensors arrive always with the same timestamp (sometimes one has 1 or 2 ms difference, but the other two have exactly the same timestamp).
I also tested the same with Android-NDK and there is exactly the same behaviour including that a change of the sampling-rate (using ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate()) has no effect.

A friend of mine tried the same things on a HTC Desire HD (with Android 2.3 and only acc- and magnetic-sensor, since he has no gyro) and there the sampling-rate of the sensors was different from each other and the sampling-rate of the acc-sensor was independent on the use of the magnetic sensor (that's what I would expect as normal behaviour).

Why becomes the acc-sensor faster if other sensors are used additionally? Did someone figure out a similar behaviour? Is this a bug? Or maybe a bug with my code?

Here is the code I used for testing with Android-SDK (I calculate the time it takes for doing 1000 measures on each of the sensors):

```
package de.tum.sdktest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestSDKActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccSensor;
private Sensor mGyroSensor;
private Sensor mMagSensor;

private int accCounter = 0;
private long lastAccTime = 0;

private int gyroCounter = 0;
private long lastGyroTime = 0;

private int magCounter = 0;
private long lastMagTime = 0;

private int measuresPerInterval = 1000;

private ArrayList<Float> accValues;
private ArrayList<Float> gyroValues;
private ArrayList<Float> magValues;


private static final String TAG = "TestSDKActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    accValues = new ArrayList<Float>();
    gyroValues = new ArrayList<Float>();
    magValues = new ArrayList<Float>();

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mGyroSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    mMagSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello World!!!");
    setContentView(tv);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}


public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public synchronized void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {



    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    {
        if(accCounter == 0 || accCounter == measuresPerInterval)
        {
            String s = String.valueOf("acc: "+(event.timestamp-lastAccTime)/1000000000.0);
            lastAccTime = event.timestamp;
            Log.i(TAG, s);
            accCounter = 0;
            accValues.clear();
        }
        accValues.add(event.values[0]);

        accCounter++;
    }
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)
    {
        if(gyroCounter == 0 || gyroCounter == measuresPerInterval)
        {
            String s = String.valueOf("gyro: "+(event.timestamp-lastGyroTime)/1000000000.0);
            lastGyroTime = event.timestamp;
            Log.i(TAG, s);
            gyroCounter = 0;
        }
        gyroValues.add(event.values[0]);

        gyroCounter++;
    }
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
    {
        if(magCounter == 0 || magCounter == measuresPerInterval)
        {
            String s = String.valueOf("mag: "+(event.timestamp-lastMagTime)/1000000000.0);
            lastMagTime = event.timestamp;
            Log.i(TAG, s);
            magCounter = 0;
        }
        magValues.add(event.values[0]);

        magCounter++;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a result of the "smart sensor" from Invensense, and is definitely not from a bug in your application level code. It's a bug in the implementation of platform software much lower down in the bowels of this device.

The [Invensense MPU3050 chip on this phone](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung-Galaxy-Nexus-Teardown/7182/2) has a Motion Processing Unit in addition to its MEMs gyroscope. It controls the accelerometer and magnetometer, coalesces the data, runs the [sensor fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion), and [sends the data back up to Android](http://riansanderson.blogspot.com/2012/03/integrating-sensors-into-android.html), where your app sees it.

From the [MPU3050 datasheet](http://invensense.com/cn/mems/gyro/documents/PS-MPU-3000A-00_v2.5.pdf):

> The embedded Digital Motion Processor (DMP) is located within the MPU-30X0 and offloads computation of 
>   motion processing algorithms from the host processor. The  DMP
>   acquires data from accelerometers,  gyroscopes, and additional sensors
>   such as magnetometers, and processes the data. [..snip...]The purpose of the  DMP is to offload
>   both timing requirements and processing power from the host  processor

Comment: Makes sence. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird. I experienced the same problem too.  So I created an App for developer to check this problem [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.mountqi.sensor.rate.checker).